# mysql php selecting sentence before after keywords

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table where a column has some entries separated by 'and'/'or' keywords. I want to know if its possible to check if theres a 'and' or a 'or' in the cell and return the values.

```
Example table:

id  company      file                           users
1    ABC      file1 and file2 and file3       men and women
2    DEF      file1                             men
3    GHI      file2                          women or men
4    jkl      file1 or file2                      women
5    mno      file1 and file2                    men
```

how can I retrieve that company ABC has file1 separately and file2 separately. i want to attach the file extension depending on type of file thats why need them separately.

In other words I will be getting a row for a selected 'id' in the table and then I am looking to see if file has 'and' or 'or' or simply just one entry. Will it be a good idea to normalize the table. if yes any suggestion on that please. Or is it convenient to do a REGEXP function with keyword maybe in mysql or PHP after I get the desired row. I have around 1000 entries. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: If you normalize the schema, and have a separate table to store filenames in you will have the benefits of using index, a more flexible schema, and a more clean query

Comment: @Dan thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to automate the process of creating a separate table where multiple entries show up for same id or would I have to do it manually on all 1000 entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Normalization way:

Create a table like this & continue with simple queries, This is the general idea not detailed solution, But it works:

```
exampleId    |    file    |    type
-------------|------------|----------
1            |    file1   |     -
1            |    file2   |    and
1            |    file3   |    and
2            |    file1   |     -
3            |    file2   |     -
4            |    file1   |     -
4            |    file2   |    or 
5            |    file1   |     -
5            |    file2   |    and
```

---

### Regexp in MySQL:

You can use internal Regexp in MySQL. if it finds `and` / `or`, it returns `1`, otherwise will return `0`:

```
$query = SELECT 'file' REGEXP '(and|or)+';
```

---

### PHP Way:

Simply retrieve the file column & after that you can check for `and` / `or` by `strpos()`. It will tell you if there is an `and` or `or` in file column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LIKE

$sql = 'SELECT company, file, users
        FROM table
        WHERE file LIKE "% and %" or file LIKE "% or %"';

~Pat